# NSolve of a Numerical Integration function

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have an equation which is itself a numerical integral function of a parameter, as follows:

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
NSolve[f[a] == 2, a,Reals]
```

However I am not able to arrive at any output.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at `FindRoot`.

Comment: Yes, I tried with FindRoot, however it does not work under every circumstances.

Comment: The way you have it `f[a]` does nothing. Since `a` does not have numerical value.  Type `f[a]` and see.

Comment: f[a] has a as numeric

Comment: Yes, but `a` itself does not have numerical value. Did you try just typing `f[a]` on its own? You'll see that Mathematica does nothing but echo back the input. You defined the function to only work on argument that is numeric. As suggested above, you can try `FindRoot`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation

Answer (score 1):

Try `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[{1, f[a] == 2}, a ]
(*{1., {a -> 6.}}*)
```

This (see comment @b.gates.you.know.what)

```
FindRoot[f[a] == 2, {a, 1 }]
```

also works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

When `FindRoot` fails, it is often due to using a poor initial estimate. To get better starting values, plot a rough inverse of `f[a]` in the region of interest.

```
ListLinePlot[{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[1, 11, 5],
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Use a rough estimate of the inverse as the starting value in `FindRoot`

```
arg[fv_] := a /. FindRoot[f[a] == fv, {a, 3/10 fv}]

arg[2] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.030148, 6.} *)
```

The result is the same as that from `NMinimize`

```
NArgMin[(f[a] - 2)^2, a] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.57372, 6.} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Numerical methods for root-finding generally have limitations, outside of which they fail.  Take your pick:

- **`NSolve`**: Finds (all) numerical solutions to (constrained) *symbolic* equations. Best on polynomial problems (especially univariate), excellent on univariate analytic function on compact domains (closed bounded intervals), less robust on multivariate problems as the dimension increases. **Never** works on the OP's type of problem. Will find the first root of an `InterpolatingFunction` and other functions on which `InverseFunction` operates successfully. Otherwise, `NSolve` **does not work** on function defined by numerical processes.
- **`FindRoot`**: Finds a single root. Usually succeeds, sometimes fails on the OP's type of problem. Compare with `NSolve` **never** working.
- **`NMinimize`** or **`FindMinimum`** on the square of the residual, or as [@Bob](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264431/4999) and [@Ulrich](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264397/4999) have done. Both find a single solution only.  Sometimes fails.
  Examples here: [`FindMinimum`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169240/4999)
  or
  [`NMinimize`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199153/4999).
- **`Plot`** based solver for real univariate problems: Jen's `findAllRoots`:
  [Find all roots of an interpolating function (solution to a differential equation)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444)  Finds all roots in an interval.  Sometimes fails.
- Package for real univariate problems: [Ted Ersek's **`RootSearch`**](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/).
- **`NDSolve`** based root search: [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16448/4999) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/4999).

Tolstoy's dictum, "Unhappy codes are unhappy in their own way," means users have to think about their problem and adjust accordingly.  And share realistic minimal working examples, if they want help.

(Defining `f` thus,
`f[a_] = a*NIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]`, removes all numerical difficulties and even opens the problem to symbolic methods.  It's obviously a toy example, and the OP states in a comment that some actual use-cases do not work with `FindRoot`, in whatever way the OP applied `FindRoot`.)